# I need a cheap, reliable, virtual webserver service

Tags: web-hosting, vps, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

So, we used linode.com for a while, and that was awesome, but I need my own virtual server now, and the problem with linode is that you had to install everything from scratch.

I'd like a server I can get my hands on with a default installation of everything necessary, the ability to use root and all that (that said, I'd prefer linux... though I have experience with windows server, just don't prefer it for my webhosting), and any kind of decent management tool online.

I don't want to spend more than $20 or $30 a month on that, and that is super important.

If I can't get a good VPS, what is a good site for hosting that isn't GoDaddy? I've only used GoDaddy, client's servers, or my current webserver on linode.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: From scratch? Not true. You pick a distribution, then you use the package management tools of that distro (such as apt for Debian) to install the packages you need (and most package management tools will do dependancy resolution for you)

Comment: What is "everything necessary" anyway? lighttpd, Perl 5.12, Catalyst, Postgresql (and a few other things that don't include PHP)? A good deal of the point in using a VPS is that you can install the software that *you* need instead of what the host thinks you might need.

Answer (score 1):

I have used both Amazon Clouds and Rackspace Clouds and like both of them. I have noticed Rackspace seems to be more inexpensive and its not as complex. Amazon AWS has more features but a steeper learning curve, but with the free tier the learning curve could be worth the effort. I use Rackspace more for my quick testing, The Centos images are quite easy to use and you can have a full LAMP Stack webserver up in 10 min or less.

Answer (score 0):

Check if Amazon's cloud offerings suit your requirement.

*As part of AWS’s [Free Usage Tier](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/), new AWS customers can get started with Amazon EC2 for free for the first 12 months.*

You can use their [monthly-cost estimation tool](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html) to see if it fits your budget

Comment: I like Amazon's cloud, but there is a lot of setup involved with potential security pitfalls if you aren't careful. The pre-rolled distributions speed things up, but it still felt a lot like installing from scratch which OP seems concerned about.

Comment: I've been messing with the AWS stuff, but it seems so confusing and so much more work than I've ever put in for simple webserver management... I honestly don't have half a clue what I'm doing, and while it says, "free for the first 12 months", how worried should I be that I'll misclick/toggle some option and suddenly be paying lots of money for it?

Answer (score 0):

Linode offers "stacks" with specific set of software installed and configured to get you going quickly. It's quicker than doing it all manually.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a response I provided on a similar question:

[Need new secure host](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13757/need-new-secure-host/13759#13759)